# using media queries with LESS

Tags: css, less

I've seen a lot of posts about nesting media queries in LESS so I dont want to repeat any of that or waste anyones time but my question is slightly different. I have a nested media query inside a `.less` file with this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px), only screen and (max-device-width: 420px){}
```

So that is on my `login.less` so my login page will be more responsive. I want to make another page responsive as well so in my `aboutMe.less` I also added the same code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px), only screen and (max-device-width: 420px){}
```

but its not triggering at all. Can you not have two media queries of the same type in css? So I would need to make a `.less` file `mediaqueries.less` and only have one instance of this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px), only screen and (max-device-width: 420px){}
```

and put all the sites code that I want that query to trigger in there, or is it possible to add the same query anywhere you want inside nested less files and im just doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

CSS supports multiple identical media queries, if you like, but CSS doesnt support nesting.

LESS, on the other hand, does support a few methods for nesting media queries. You can read about it here: http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-scoping-extend-inside-media

Example:

```
@media screen {
  @media (min-width: 1023px) {
    .selector {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
  .selector {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

LESS also supports nesting media queries below selectors like this:

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  @media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
    width: 768px;
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
  footer {
    width: 768px;
  }
}
```

If this doesnt answer your question, then please post the relevant part of your LESS file(s).

Comment: It seems the nested media query started working the other day. I think I had messed up css somewhere and when I refactored a bunch of stuff the media query started working. Thanks for the info this is a great reference for me!

Answer (score -1):

For media rules on `less` my recommendation is use [Escaping](https://lesscss.org/#escaping).

Sample:

```less
@min768: ~"(min-width: 768px)";

.element {
  @media @min768 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the second colon will fale some LESS compilers